# Python data structures-Josephus Circle algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, circular-list, josephus

I was implementing Josephus circle algorithm in Python. I am having a small doubt related to an error which was coming when i wrote prev=Node(0) and head=Node(0). The error removed when I wrote head=Node(0) prev=head. Why the error was coming when I wrote prev=Node(0) and head=Node(0).

```
def getJosephusCircle(n, m):
    class Node:
        def __init__(self, data=None, next=None):
            self.setData(data)
            self.setNext(next)
        def setData(self,data):
            self.data=data
        def getData(self):
            return self.data
        def setNext(self,next):
            self.next=next
        def getNext(self):
            return self.next
        def hasNext(self):
            return self.next!=None

    #circular linked list loop
    head=Node(0)
    prev=head
    for i in range(1,n):
        currentNode=Node(i)
        prev.setNext(currentNode)
        prev=currentNode
    prev.setNext(head)
    currentNode=head
    counter=0
    answer=[]
    while currentNode.getNext()!= currentNode:
        counter+=1
        if counter == m:
            counter = 0
            prev.setNext(currentNode.next)
            answer.append(currentNode.getData())
        else:
            prev=currentNode
            currentNode=currentNode.getNext()
    answer.append(currentNode.getData())
    return answer
print(getJosephusCircle(6,3))
```

error shown--- while currentNode.getNext()!= currentNode:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'getNext'

Thank You

Comment: Well, that's what `Node.hasNext` is for...

Comment: You want `prev` to start out pointing at the same object as `head`. That doesn't happen when you create two separate `Node(0)` objects.

Comment: @ForceBru there is no need to use Node.hasNext, it's just a part of class...There is no problem with the algorithm, it's correct. But the problem occurs when i change the 2 lines below comment written as #circular linked list loop, i changed it to prev=Node(0) and head=Node(0), this causes error mentioned in the question.I am not able to understand why this happens.

Comment: @glibdud Why can't Node(0) can be pointed by both variables i.e. head and prev. What's the reason?

Comment: It can be, the way you have it here. But when you do `head=Node(0)`, `prev=Node(0)`, you're making two independent `Node` objects and assigning one to each name. If you `id(head)` and `id(prev)`, you'll see that they're not the same object.